# Kentico Custom WebPart button on Click event

Tags: onclick, web-parts, kentico

I've created a custom webpart to register a new user. I added a button to register and on-click event register I write my code . when I add the web part to kentico it gives my error loading the webpart ,when I remove the on-click event it works fine . How I could solve this and I need to write the code inside the event. thanks

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include 
the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code  necessary 
to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem 
statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve].

Comment: Please provide an example of the click event handler that you have written. Is it async, for example?

Answer (score 1):

Have you followed the [Creating new webparts](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/custom-development/developing-web-parts/creating-new-web-parts) example in the Kentico documentation?  Make sure that your user control inherits from one of the base classes listed there.

It might also help if you paste the error from the [Kentico event log](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/developing-websites/troubleshooting-websites/working-with-the-system-event-log), as this may give more of a clue as to what is not working.